# Using kubectl with an aws role that can only be assumed when the underlying user profile provides an MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am trying to access an EKS cluster that is owned by a role (call it OwnerRole). To switch to this role, the authorized user has to have authenticated using MFA.

Here are the relevant configs in my system:
.aws/config

```
[profile AuthorizedUser]
    region = us-east-1
    output = json
    mfa_serial = <ARN of the user's MFA device>

[profile RoleProfileUsedByKubectl]
    source_profile = AuthorizedUser
    role_arn = <ARN of the OwnerRole role>
```

Here is the relevant section of the kubectl config

```
- name: <username in context>
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - <name of the cluster>
      command: aws
      env:
      - name: AWS_PROFILE
        value: RoleProfileUsedByKubectl
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: false
```

However, here's what is happening.

When I run:

```
$ kubectl config use-context <context name>
Switched to context "<context name>"
$
$ kubectl get po -A
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: <user ARN> is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: <role ARN>
....
<repeat 4 more times>
....
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254
```

I assume this is because when I switched the context, it was supposed to first use the AuthorizedUser profile and ask me for MFA token, but does not. So, it just logged me in as AuthorizedUser without the MFA token and tried to assume the OwnerRole - which gets denied due to lack of MFA.

However, if I tweak the .aws config slightly as below (change the location of the mfa_serial to the role profile), at least the AWS commands work, but not the kubectl:

```
[profile AuthorizedUser]
    region = us-east-1
    output = json

[profile RoleProfileUsedByKubectl]
    source_profile = AuthorizedUser
    mfa_serial = <ARN of the user's MFA device>
    role_arn = <ARN of the OwnerRole role>

$ aws eks list-nodegroups --cluster-name <cluster name> --region us-east-1 --profile RoleProfileUsedByKubectl
Enter MFA code for <MFA ARN>: 
{
    "nodegroups": [
        "<node group name list>"
    ]
}
$
$ kubectl get po -A
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 172.16.88.123:443: i/o timeout
$
```

Could this be because the firewall or a security group is blocking kubectl's access? Please advice.

Comment: SSO will make that easier.  Way better than IAM users for MFA ergonomics

Comment: Hope you acquired a token via awscli first before trying the kubectl? Also use "aws eks update-kubeconfig --region <<region>> --name <<your cluster name>>.
Run kubectl after above command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what finally worked for me:

.kube/config

```
users:
- name: <username listed in context>
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - <clustername>
      command: aws
      env:
      - name: AWS_PROFILE
        value: <aws_profile_name>
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: false
```

.aws/config

```
[profile <base_profile>]
    region = us-east-1
    output = json

[profile <aws_profile_name>]
    source_profile = <base_profile> 
    mfa_serial = <arn of mfa>
    role_arn = <arn of target role that needs mfa>
    role_session_name = <optional_but_easy_to_identify_in_logs>
```

Now, every time I try to switch context, it prompts me for MFA and switches without issues.